# Auth::guard() is working wrong in view laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-authentication

i have a controller:

```
if( Auth::attempt(['mssv' => $username,'password' =>$password])) {
      $success = new MessageBag(['successlogin' => 'Login Success]);
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors($success);
}
elseif( Auth::guard('admins')->attempt(['manv' => $username,'password' =>$password])) {
      $success = new MessageBag(['successlogin' => 'Login Success]);
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors($success);
}
else {
      $errors = new MessageBag(['errorlogin' => 'Login Fail']);
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors($errors);
}
```

and view:

```
@guest
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Guest page</a>
      </li>
@endguest
@auth
 @if(Auth()->guard('admins')->check())
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Admin Page</a>
  </li>
 @elseif(Auth()->user()->check())
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">User Page</a>
  </li>
 @endif
@endauth
```

but when i login with user account, it show  Admin page. when i login with admin account, it show guest page, i dont know why, please help!

Comment: Have you tried placing your admin login guard before your regular guard?

Comment: I think my problem is that I have not logged out of admins yet. but when i logout and login with any account again, guest page still show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your problem is do not logout admins account before, and you can try this to replate @guest

```
@if(!Auth::check() && !Auth()->guard('admins')->check())
//anything 
@endif
```

goodluck!